# How to run su in remote machine

Tags: remote-server, su

I am running below command in host machine as root

cat file1 | ssh remoteserver "su - differentuser;cat >> file1"

It is not working. it is creating file1 in root home folder in remote server.
But i want this to be created in different user home folder and different user as owner.

Could anyone please help me.
I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

The cat command will run after command `su` finishes and goes back to logged ssh user.

To run cat inside su you have to run with `-c` parameter:

```
cat file1 | ssh remoteserver "su -l differentuser -c 'cat >> file1'"

cat file1 | ssh remoteserver "su differentuser -c 'cat >> ~/file1'"
```

Comment: @user3180371 strange, -l parameter should be available too, at least in Linux/BSD. You can try changing from "-l" to "-".